# Assigning uninitilialized void* pointer

Tags: c, gcc, glibc

```
#include <stdio.h>

void wat(void *ptr){
    *(int*)ptr = 0x4A424F4B;
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    FILE *wtf = fopen("wat", "wb");
    void *ptr;
    wat(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

This actually **compiles and executes without errors**, you can even `fwrite` contents of `*(int*)ptr` and you'll get `0x4A424F4B`. However, when you remove this line:

```
FILE *wtf = fopen("wat", "wb");
```

`*(int*)ptr = 0x4A424F4B;` will suddenly cause a segmentation fault. Why?

Comment: This program will cause a undefined behavior. Until unless you pass a valid address to function wat, you cant expect the correct result

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, your code has [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

It *happens* to not blow up on your particular platform using your particular compiler because the uninitialized `ptr` happens to contain the address of some writable memory. Since we don't know where `ptr` is pointing, we can't know what harm the assignment is doing.

Moving things around changes the addresses, and things "break" (strictly speaking, they weren't really working in the first place).

Answer (score 3):

It's undefined behavior, so anything could happen.

Probably what happened is, with this line

```
FILE *wtf = fopen("wat", "wb");
```

A valid pointer value is left in the stack. Then the uninitialized `ptr` gets it. But again, undefined behavior, you shouldn't rely on it.

Answer (score 2):

```
*(int*)ptr = 0x4A424F4B;
```

means write the integer value `0x4A424F4B` into the address that the integer pointer `ptr` points to. Since you are not initializing the `ptr`, its behaviour is not defined. The fact the it works in some cases is therefore irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

It compiles, but you do get warnings:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o ptr ptr.c
ptr.c: In function ‘main’:
ptr.c:9:11: warning: unused variable ‘wtf’ [-Wunused-variable]
     FILE *wtf = fopen("wat", "wb");
           ^
ptr.c:11:5: warning: ‘ptr’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     wat(ptr);
     ^
```

And if you enable the address sanitizer, it will not execute without errors:

```
$ gcc -fsanitize=address -o ptr ptr.c
$ ./ptr
=================================================================
==3280==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc     0x00000040080d sp 0x7ffffa1f4940 bp 0x7ffffa1f4950 T0)
    #0 0x40080c in wat (/tmp/ptr+0x40080c)
    #1 0x400843 in main (/tmp/ptr+0x400843)
    #2 0x7fa048110b44 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b44)
    #3 0x4006f8 (/tmp/ptr+0x4006f8)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV ??:0 wat
==3280==ABORTING
```

But yeah, C by default does not come with safety.

Comment: I didn't get any warning, are you using `-Wall`?

Comment: @M132 I show the commands I use :) Yes, I use -Wall. C compilers usually don't give warnings unless you ask for them.

Comment: @M132 and on a real projects I actually tend to use `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion`